# how to get full commit log from a shallow clone?

Tags: git, git-log, shallow-clone

Is it possible to get the commit log history from a local copy which is a shallow clone `(--depth = 1)`

I am using shallow clone in my jenkins build job to get the code and build but the changelog is not complete because I am using shallow clone. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Why do you want to see your Git log beyond 1 commit?  By definition, the older commits are not there.

Comment: I am also using the hockeyapp plugin and passing the changelog as release notes. and using shallow clone, the change log does not includes all the changes done in the build.

Answer (score 3):

In theory you can do a partially shallow clone where all of the `commit` objects are cloned but the `tree` and `blob` objects are only cloned to a depth of 1:

```
git clone --filter=tree:1 <repo>
```

However Github does not support this option:

```
fatal: remote error: filter 'tree' not supported (maximum depth: 0, but got: 1)
```

It works on GitLab as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot.

But if it helps, you can get a list of tags (if your jenkins job wants to check a tag) via [git ls-remote](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html).

Mort