# Jenkins - Impact of shallow clone

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have setup Jenkins with Git SCM enabled.

Since Git server is present in another country with slow intranet network connection, Git sync is too slow for me. it fails many times.

I read some suggestions online saying 'enable shallow clone'.

But my worry is will i miss something if i do shallow clone. Something like 'change history'.

it is a Xamarin Android C# solution, wondering will it be safe to do shallow clone.

Can shallow clone resolve my slow network issue.? How it impacts as a jenkins job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only impact is for your job to have a [limited view of the cloned/fetched history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30158978/6309) (since it is a [shallow one](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/advanced-git-jenkins), with limited depth)

But you will not miss any *new change in history: the [JENKINS Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) would still detect new commits on the remote repo side. (and, if the workspace is not cleaned at each new job, would [perform a regular fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41647002/6309))

Comment: Yes. When Shallow clone of depth 1 is configured. Jenkins is not showing Source code Changes.

Comment: I think for me it does show source code changes even with `depth: 1`, but _not_ in the first build of a new branch (the one with number `#1` and `/1` in the URL); I believe that never shows any changes for me, irrespective of `depth`. I've only tested that a bit though, not thoroughly.

Comment: @nh2 OK. What version of Jenkins, JenkinsGit plugin and Git itself are you using?

Comment: @VonC Note my reply to @ManiVannan's "Jenkins is not showing Source code Changes". git `2.25.4`, Jenkins `2.222.1`, `Git` plugin `4.3.0`.